# How can I print symbols from a String to a txt file?

Tags: java, string, symbols

This is what I have tryed to do:

```
 String raw = dstream.readLine();
                  raw = raw.replaceAll("Up"," ↑ ");
                  raw = raw.replaceAll("Right"," → ");
                System.out.println(raw);
```

This is part of an easy program that receives Strings and prints them to a text file: "java -jar Server.jar > a.txt".

The problem is this:
Insted of ↑ or → , I get those in the txt file: "â†•  â†•  â†•  â†‘"

Comment: Why not write to the file in the Java code? That way, you'd have control over character sets...

Comment: How do you prove your txt-file? With cat/type? With an editor? Does the editor use the correct character encoding (the same like when writing the Javacode)?

Comment: It appears you are writing your file using UTF-8 (which suggests you’re running your program in OS X or Linux), then reading it using Microsoft Notepad or some other editor or command that assumes a one-byte Windows-125x character set.  '↑' is represented as the three bytes e2 86 95 in UTF-8, but if those bytes are each treated as individual Windows-125x characters, e2 is 'â', 86 is '†' (dagger), and 95 is '‘' (opening single quote).  View the file on the same machine on which you created it, or use a smarter editor.

Answer (score 0):

```
cat Upright.java 
public class Upright
{
    public static void main (String args[])
    {
        String raw ="Left - Down - Up - Right - East - West";
        raw = raw.replaceAll("Up"," ↑ ");
        raw = raw.replaceAll("Right"," → ");
        System.out.println(raw);
    }
}
java Upright > upright.txt && cat upright.txt 
Left - Down -  ↑  -  →  - East - West
```

Works like a charm. 
The character encoding of the tool, you use to produce the source, has to match the tool for looking at the output file.